# Read All Rows and Columns Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have excel sheet with 4 columns and 4 rows. When I read the columns and rows `Count` with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkSheet` the count of rows and columns are 1048576 for rows and for columns 16384. The count must be 4 for rows and 4 for columns. What did I miss ?

```
            ApplicationClass excelApp = null;
            Workbook myWorkBook = null;
            Worksheet mySheet = null;
            Range dataRange = null;
            excelApp = new ApplicationClass();
            myWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Dev2Admin\Desktop\Employees.xlsx");
            mySheet = (Worksheet)myWorkBook.Sheets["Sheet1"];


            for (int row = 1; row < mySheet.Rows.Count; row++) // Count is 1048576 instead of 4
            {
                for (int col = 1; col < mySheet.Columns.Count; col++) // Count is 16384 instead of 4
                {
                    dataRange = (Range)mySheet.Cells[row, col];
                    Console.Write(String.Format(dataRange.Value2.ToString() + " "));
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

Answer (score 7):

You have omitted `UsedRange` property, the correct used column or row count on your sheet you get like this:

```
  int totalColumns = mySheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
  int totalRows = mySheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also one more thing, that rows and colums start with 1 not 0 so you need to set the for loops range to <= to get all data, not just <