# C# Copy all data of multiple excel into one single worksheet

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two excel files Excel1 and Excel2.

I want to copy all rows of Excel1 and Excel2 into new Excel3 single sheet.

I tried the below code but it copy all Excel1 and Excel2 into two different sheet of single excel file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = true;
            foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
            {
                app.Workbooks.Add(@"C:\Users\Zest\Documents\" + postedFile.FileName);
            }

            for (int i = 2; i <= app.Workbooks.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets.Count; j++)
                {
                    Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets[j];
                    ws.Copy(app.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1]);
                }
            }
            app.Workbooks[1].SaveCopyAs(@"D:\New folder\result.xlsx");
            app.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I am new in C#, please help me to fix this.

Comment: @PeterSmith, because it is asp.net webforms... Other than that, do not use Interop, especially for websites. Look into libraries like EPPlus.

Comment: @PeterSmith I have created this project on Asp.Net c#. If you want I can remove it.

Comment: You only add single Worksheets. I never worked with this library but i think you have to add just the first worksheet and then add every single cell from the second excel to this first worksheet. Maybe this post can help you to see how to iterate trough all cells: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833425 .

Comment: I can give you an EPPlus example if you like? You want to upload multiple excel files and merge then into one sheet?